# How can I have a preview of different website in my sidebar?

Tags: wordpress, widget

I have two websites, and I want to have a preview of my other website in the sidebar. I have put [PHP Code Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-widget/) in my sidebar and use this code for redirection:

```
 <?php header( 'Location: http://www.SiteUrl.com/new_page.html' ) ; ?>
```

but it does not work. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an Iframe to display adifferent webpage in it:
set desired source and width/height. If you need to scale the webpage in it you can give it some css.

```html
<iframe width="1024" height="768" src="http://www.bbc.com">
```